# Setting levenshtein in a variable in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
from word 
WHERE levenshtein(LOWER(name), LOWER('door')) <= 3 
ORDER BY levenshtein(LOWER(name), LOWER('door')) ASC 
LIMIT 5
```

Question is how can I cache (with the help of as) result of `levenshtein` function to avoid repetition.

Something like

```
SELECT *, levenshtein(LOWER(name), LOWER('door')) as distance...
```

Comment: If the function is defined as `stable` (or `immutable`) Postgres will cache that automatically.

Comment: Is levenshtein is immutable?

Comment: `t=# \sf levenshtein(text,text)
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.levenshtein(text, text)
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE c
 IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT
AS '$libdir/fuzzystrmatch', $function$levenshtein$function$
`